# How to grep the last character of each row?

Tags: grep

I want to grep all lines that contain _P at the end.

For example a file may contain

```
stuff_C
stuff_P
things_C
things_P
stu_P_ff
thi_P_ngs
```

I only want to capture `stuff_P` & `things_P` sent to stdout

Answer (score 4):

You can use "[anchor characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)" to achieve this.

```
grep "[[:print:]]*_P$" file.txt
```

or, more simply (as per @JeffSchaller's comment)

```
grep "_P$" file.txt
```

should achieve what you want.

Comment: Depending on the requirement to have stuff before `_P`, you could drop `[[:print:]]*`

Comment: @JeffSchaller correct, I have included it.

Comment: Maybe the Q was going through some last-minute editing, but the current version doesn't ask for "ending in `C`"; and the current version of your Answer doesn't anchor the second grep to EOL...

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, I actually forgot the very anchor I was talking about in my edit. As for the question, I was pretty sure I saw a `_C` there, too; maybe I was mistaken. Anyway, I edited the answer accordingly; thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score -2):

A simple example - found one invalid CNAME entry, and one w an extra space at the end.  Ignoring the comment lines ( ;; in bind )

> DNSint04 # cat /var/named/internal/db.abanet.org | grep -v ^; | grep
> -i cname | grep -v ".$"
>
> aba-sepm-z                      IN CNAME sepm-z abavideo
> IN CNAME  vidxxxxchifw01.abanet.org.
>
> DNSint04 #

Comment: Your example is invalid: `-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `|'`